# Oracle SQL Select Long Data Type

Tags: oracle, select, types, long-integer

How can I get data with long data type as text from a table in Oracle database? When I run this code SELECT S.ISTEK_NO,S.RAPORX FROM RAD_SONUC S, widememo is returned to me....
**Sample code
SELECT S.RAPORX FROM RAD_SONUC S**

Comment: Your client software is responsible for deciding how to handle longs for display to human ad-hoc queries. You'll have to look into the options for whatever software you're using. Alternatively, a pipelined function could be built that uses PL/SQL to read the table, convert the long to a CLOB by assignment to local PL/SQL variable, then emit rows with a CLOB in place of the original long. That too requires special client handling to display properly but is likely to be better supported.